# Pandas dataframe - do I have 5 samples within 123ms?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe, whose one column is a timestamp with millisecond granularity. The rows are sorted chronologically. I want to check if any 5 samples are within 123ms interval of each other (t[i+4]-t[i] < 123ms for some i). How do I do that without naive looping through the dataframe? This is the only way I know, and I don't have an idea how to even try something different.

Comment: Can you provide a short data sample? Makes it easier to be certain that the lines provided actually work.

Comment: Just use `diff` e.g. `df['timestamp'].diff(5) > 123ms` or similar